# Why does my Java code return a memory address and not a string?

Tags: java

I am calling a WSDL service from PlaneXML - API reference here
https://flightwise.com/documentation/39/PlaneXML_API_Reference.html#AirportInfo

My code:

```
public static void airportName() throws RemoteException{
    String lax = "LAX";       
    PlaneXMLv1SoapProxy foo = new PlaneXMLv1SoapProxy();
    Airport [] info = foo.airportInfo(lax);
    System.out.println("output 1: " + info);
    System.out.println("output 2: " + info.toString());
    System.out.println("output 3: " + info[0]);
}
```

My output:

```
output 1: [Lcom.flightwise.planexml.ws.Airport;@604ed9f0
output 2: [Lcom.flightwise.planexml.ws.Airport;@604ed9f0
test
test
output 3: com.flightwise.planexml.ws.Airport@9117a1a4
```

Why do I return these memory addresses and not a string?
Any ideas what might be causing the "test" output?

Comment: Does your class overwrite `toString()`? Probably not. As such, it will use the default implementation of [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--). Ah, and because it's an array you are trying to print at the beginning. Use `Arrays.toString(array)` instead. You'll still have to overwrite `toString()` for your Airport class.

Comment: can you post your class airport ?

Comment: This is not memory address, It is full name of class + hash code of that object of same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have answered, you are:

1- Printing the array itself.
2- Using toString() without an override.
3- Printing an Airport Object.
If you want to print specific things about the **Airport**, you need to use the properties explicitly. Also, read the documentaion https://flightwise.com/documentation/39/PlaneXML_API_Reference.html#Airport

It reads:

> Provides basic information on an airport.
>
> Ident As String
> ICAO As String
> Location As String
> Lat As Double
> Lon As Double
> Elev As Int32
> GMTOffset As Short
> DST As Short

Comment: Thanks - how can I pass in the requested property, e.g. Ident? I see now how I'm trying to print the object and not actually telling it what I want to know.

Comment: Can you give me a link to the API. I mean the jar or the zip file you are using.

Comment: I have the axis2 jar in my build path, but am not certain if it's being called. It is here: 'http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadaxis2transporthttp161jar.html'. The API overview is at 'flightwise.com/planeXML_API.html' - it but as you found the documentation I'm sure you've seen that also.

Comment: I wasn't talking about this API. I was talking about the PlaneXML API which has the Airport Class. Do you have the source of Airport class? If not try using info[0].getIdent(); or info[0].Ident; You cannot be sure unless you have the javadoc or the sources.

Comment: Success - I pass the requested property in as in your instruction above. Thanks very much for your patience and help.

Comment: @BenMayo You're welcome. We are a community. We need to teach and learn each day. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you implement `toString()` method of `Airport` object you can see strings on console.

Comment: Only for the third line. The first two lines will execute `toString()` on the Array, not an Airport object.

Answer (score 0):

toString() doesn't return an address . It returns

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: How can / why should an answer be posted as a comment?

Comment: Well the real issue here is that they're calling (implicitly and explicitly) the `toString()` method on an array. This reads as though you're simply correcting the asker's assertion that what they're seeing in the output is a memory address.

Comment: @JonK - I answered this part - "Why do I return these memory addresses and not a string?"

Answer (score 0):

Since `info` is an array of `String`, that's why the output is `[Lcom.flightwise.planexml.ws.Airport;@604ed9f0` and **not a `String`**, and if you want to print the `toString()` (if you have overrided) method of your `Airport` class, then just do :

```
System.out.println(info[0].toString()) // you can use any index in place of 0
```